# Timeout in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am getting the following error in running an old ASP.NET application:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Request timed out.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web 
request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it 
originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. 
Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using 
the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed out.]

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET 
Version:4.8.9032.0
```

I have looked around, but nothing helped.

Can someone please tell me if it's possible to allocate more time? I see that it takes about 115 sec. to fail. Another "funny" detail is that if I put it into a debugging mode it's not crashing.

Thanks